# How to use an object that is available in JSP within a scriptlet, can this be done

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a variable called `statements` which I am iterating over and naming `row`

```
<c:forEach items="${statements}" var="row">
```

Can I now use this variable `row` in a scriptlet if I do something like

```
<% ArrayList<String> myRows = **** something here *** %>
```

What do I have to replace **** something here *** with to be able to do this.

Note: I know in theory this is bad, as far as I can see the problem I have (which is more complicated that this, can only be solved this way.

Comment: where have you stored `statements` , is it in session,request where ?

Comment: I don't really know, I am using the Stripes framework, I think it comes as part of the response and I can simply grab it using EL when I am in the JSP.

Answer (score 2):

It's available as an attribute of the page, request, session or application scope. If the scope is known, just call `getAttribute()` on the scope of interest.

```
<%
    Object pageAttribute = pageContext.getAttribute("name");
    Object requestAttribute = request.getAttribute("name");
    Object sessionAttribute = session.getAttribute("name");
    Object applicationAttribute = application.getAttribute("name");
%>
```

Or if the scope is unknown, use `PageContext#findAttribute()`. It searches in subsequently the page, request, session and application scopes and returns the first match.

```
<%
    Object unknownScopedAttribute = pageContext.findAttribute("name");
%>
```

The above is also basically what EL is doing under the covers.

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, this is definitely a workaround. If you elaborate in detail *why* need to do this, then we may be able to come up with real solutions instead of workarounds. In the meanwhile, read this thoroughly: [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Answer (score -2):

simple answer: don't use scriptlets.
complex answer: don't use scriptlets.

And that's all there is to it, really: don't use scriptlets.

If you knew how the JSTL code works, where it gets the ${statements} value from, you'd know how to use it in a scriptlet as well.
But as you shouldn't use scriptlets, I'm not going to tell you any more, I'd only be leading you towards your doom and I don't intend to do that.
Anyway, unless your ${statements} is a `Collection<List<String>>` your "row" local is never going to be a `List<String>` :)